# How to do exact complex JSON API response matching using Karate JS

Tags: cucumber, karate

Suppose this is my API Response:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "listObjects": [
    {
      "id": 100,
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want this to be validated with this response:

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "listObjects": [
    {
      "id": 100,
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
    }
  ]
}
```

For this i'm doing: `response == myJson`. This works perfectly!

But the `listObjects` can be in any order. The response sometimes can be like:

```
  "name": "hello-world",
  "listObjects": [
    {
      "id": 200,
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
    }
  ]
}
```

In such cases how do I do exact json matching in just one line?
I do not want to do individual key matching. 
It should be done in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 2 lines. Read the docs to understand this more:

```
* def list = [{ id: 200 }, { id: 100 }]
* def response =
"""
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "listObjects": [
    {
      "id": 100,
    },
    {
      "id": 200,
    }
  ]
}
"""
* match response.listObjects contains only list
* match response == { name: 'hello-world', listObjects: '#(^^list)' }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! But this is not a generic solution. If I do this i'm binding my test cases with the payloads. Let's say in future the response payload changes, then I'll have to change the code as well. 
What I'm hoping to do is:
`* match response == WhatEverJsonFileIProvide`.
So that in case the payloads changes, i'll just have to make changes to the json file only and not the actual test case. 
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @s3e3 why don't you spend some time reading the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files so you can do `* match response = read('some.json')` - and look for "embedded expressions" also in the docs. if you find *that* too complicated, all the best finding a framework to do the magic you are expecting :)

Comment: yea thats what I meant when I say `WhatEverJsonFileIProvide `. Looks like you cant help me. you dont even seem to understand the problem.

Comment: I am doing this `* match response = read('some.json')` but the list objects in response CAN BE IN ANY ORDER so it's failing sometimes.
And please do not point to docs one more time. There isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: @s3e3 and what I am saying is you want a complex assertion in one line which is just not possible in Karate. I challenge you to find any framework in which this is possible. peace. so yes, what you are expecting is magic.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, first you can sort the response from API explicitly using 'id'. There are several libraries which will sort array using one particular key. Using those, you can sort actual API response first in a way how your expected JSON looks and compare them using equals